# How to convert Date from facebook api into android app date format

Tags: android

I am developing an app which is similiar to android facebook app.

I got an created time field from facebook app

```
  "created_time": "2012-11-28T12:53:40+0000",
```

So, how can I convert this into date format of android facebook app,like

```
2hours ago,
yesterday at 5:30pm etc
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
String getCreatedTime = JOConversations.getString("created_time");
long finalTimeStamp = Long.valueOf(getCreatedTime);
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ssZ");

SimpleDateFormat formatter = getDateFormat();
ParsePosition pos = new ParsePosition(0);
long then = formatter.parse(timestamp, pos).getTime();
long now = new Date().getTime();

long seconds = (now - then)/1000;
long minutes = seconds/60;
long hours = minutes/60;
long days = hours/24;

String friendly = null;
long num = 0;
if (days > 0) {
    num = days;
    friendly = days + " day";
} else if (hours > 0) {
    num = hours;
    friendly = hours + " hour";
} else if (minutes > 0) {
    num = minutes;
    friendly = minutes + " minute";
} else {
    num = seconds;
    friendly = seconds + " second";
}
if (num > 1) {
    friendly += "s";
}
String postTimeStamp = friendly.toUpperCase() + " AGO";
```

And a helper method for this bit here: `SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ssZ");` is

```
private static SimpleDateFormat getDateFormat() {
    return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ssZ");
}
```

I derived this code block from the `StreamRenderer.java` in the Facebook SDK exmples on GitHub here: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/examples/stream/src/com/facebook/stream/StreamRenderer.java (Check Line No. 380 onwards)

It does not deal with the scenario *yesterday at 5:30pm*. But this should get you started.

Comment: long now = new Date().getTime(); at this point it is asking me to add arguments

Comment: @user1761316: Arguments? I don't face that problem. I copied it from a production app's code.

Comment: When I scroll the list,I am getting bitmap size exceeds vm budget error.I am facing this problem from many days.I tried with loading the data when scroll is in off state,but still I am facing the same problem.Did you face any of these problems?

Comment: @user1761316: In the early stages of development, I did, in fact, face the same problem. But that was sorted out by using Fedor's [Lazy Loading](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList) solution. That sorted it all out. You should give that a try.

Comment: As you said,that pulltorefresh has header,which gives me listview count as 1. can u tell me the scrollListener condition to load more data.I wrote   (if (!loading && (firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount+2) == totalItemCount+1){) like this,but it is giving me only some data I mean only few pages.

Comment: JOConversations not exit in my side how to get them?

Comment: @DhruvRaval: The timestamp looks like this as illustrated in the question _"created_time": "2012-11-28T12:53:40+0000",_. This is what is returned by the Facebook API. The `JOConversations` in the example is an instance of a JSON Object used in my code. You will need to substitute that with your JSON object instance.

Comment: @DhruvRaval: Awesome. Glad to have helped. :-)