# Inconsistent time difference in facebook post graph API

Tags: json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Recently, i'm making an application which retrieve facebook posts of a page for a certain date. The issue that i've encountered is, there are some inconsistencies between the post unix time and the displayed date for some posts.

This is an example that i've found:

Created time from JSON reponse : "created_time": "2013-03-09T18:58:20+0000"

Displayed date :March 10, 2013 at 1:58am

The time difference is : 1:58 am - 18: 58 pm =  7 hr

then, for another post:
Created time from JSON reponse : "created_time": "2013-03-09T19:03:17+0000"

Displayed date :March 10, 2013 at 3:03am

The time difference is : 3:03 am - 19: 03 pm =  8 hr

And no, I didn't change my timezone inbetween displaying those two JSON response.
I use graph API and 'since until' parameter with unix timestamp for getting the JSON response.

Is there anyone who can explain this issue? 
Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Solved it, it's because of daylight saving time that facebook use

Answer (score 0):

After much more time spending on it..i found this helpful link to implement in my project...
 i hope it may helpful to u also..

[How to convert Date from facebook api into android app date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13607209/how-to-convert-date-from-facebook-api-into-android-app-date-format)