# Android converting Facebook time to Date

Tags: java, android, date, simpledateformat

I've received this start_time from my facebook query:

```
2013-05-30T19:30:00+0300
```

how can i parse it to Date in Android ?

I've tried this:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss' '");
```

Comment: I think by using [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: @Kedarnath yeah but what is the string format? i've update my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ` format as below...

```
String dateString = "2013-05-30T19:30:00+0300";

SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
Date date = dateFormat.parse(dateString);

dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm");
String formatedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

Log.d("Date", formatedDate);
```

**Output:**

```
03-10 18:29:47.074: D/Date(27257): 2013-05-30 10:30
```

Comment: @HS +1 up for your _Awesome_ answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this link:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13607418/3110609

You need to use SimpleDateFormat but need to manage correctly